# Raku vs Perl benchmarking using prime numbers

Tags: benchmarking, primes, raku, perl

This is a discussion moved from this [HN thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16720027) here, regarding benchmarking Perl6 vs. Perl5 vs. other languages using an algorithm which implements the [Sieve of Sundaram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram) for finding prime numbers.

Here's original code in the original thread:

[perl5](https://p.thorsen.pm/2d70bb2da612) 0m0.156s

[perl6](https://p.thorsen.pm/ab1769fe2778) 0m6.615s

The problem is that the Perl6 version takes too long to find primes, compared to the Perl5 implementation. Part of it is due to using float as input, but still, it's too slow.

The objective is not necessarily to optimize the algorithm, but rather to identify why Perl6 is so slow compared to other languages.

Comment: See also the 2017 SO [How do I efficiently generate a list of primes in Raku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607801/perl6-vs-perl5-benchmarking-using-prime-numbers). Two key quotes from the summary of the solutions, as written in the question author's own nanswer: "A sieve in Raku code isn't as slow as I feared, as long as you optimize things a bit" and "added Curt Tilmes' [`Primesieve`](https://github.com/CurtTilmes/raku-primesieve) module. Wow, it's fast!"

Answer (score 14):

Turns out that even though primes are integers, in your Perl 6 version, every calculation was done by using floating point. And this was caused by the call to the subroutine. If you would do:

```
sieve_sundaram(1000)
```

instead of:

```
sieve_sundaram(1e3)
```

then it all of a sudden becomes 4x as fast. In Perl 5 you never know what you're dealing with with regards to values. In Perl 6 if you tell it to use a floating point, it will infect all calculations to be in floating point afterwards. `1e3` is a floating point value. `1000` is an integer in Perl 6.

Also, you seem to have a sub-optimal algorithm: the second `foreach` doesn't need to go from `1..$n`, but can go from `$i..$n` instead. This brings down the runtime of the Perl 5 version of the code to 89 msecs for me.

Since your program is not using BigInt in the Perl 5 version, it is basically using native integers. In Perl 6, all integer calculations are always BigInts, unless you mark them as native. If I adjust your Perl 6 version for this, the runtime goes down from 4671 msecs to 414 msecs for this version:

```
sub sieve_sundaram(int $n) {
    my %a;
    my int @s = 2;
    my int $m = $n div 2 - 1;
    for 1..$n -> int $i {
        for $i..$n -> int $j {
            my int $p = $i + $j + 2 * $i * $j;
            if $p < $m {
                %a{$p} = True;
            }
        }
    }
    for 1..$m -> int $k {
        if ! %a{$k} {
            my int $q = 2 * $k + 1;
            @s.push($q);
        }
    }

    return @s;
}

sieve_sundaram(1000);
```

So, about 11x faster than before. And just under 5x as slow as the Perl 5 version.

The most idiomatic version for getting primes in Perl 6 is:

```
(1..1000).grep( *.is-prime )
```

Which for me executes within noise of your original Perl 5 algorithm. For larger values on multi-CPU machines, I would write this as:

```
(1..2500).hyper.grep( *.is-prime )
```

Around 2500 it becomes faster to `hyper` it, so the work gets automatically distributed over multiple CPU's.

Comment: Just another plug for RT [130982](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=130982#txn-1509226).  If you convert all the range loops like ... `for 1..$n -> int $i` to `loop (my int $i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++)` then I get performance almost doubling again.

Comment: Why does it perform all caculations using BigInt if no type hints are specified rather than upgrade from int to Bigint whenever int overflows, like Ruby does?

Comment: @petre An Int in Perl 6 is an instance of the Int object type. It turns out that mixing the object type Int, and the native type int is slower than just using Int everywhere because many things will autobox an int into an Int.

Comment: After doing the i..n optimization on both perls and ruby, and the type hints on perl6, it turns out ruby is 145% faster than perl5 and 347% faster than perl6 using the [same algorithm](https://p.thorsen.pm/4f7e6001de4b) up to 10k.

Comment: nice, but why does it stop after a few dozen ?> (1..2500).hyper.grep( *.is-prime ).say
(2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 101 103 107 109 113 127 131 137 139 149 151 157 163 167 173 179 181 191 193 197 199 211 223 227 229 233 239 241 251 257 263 269 271 277 281 283 293 307 311 313 317 331 337 347 349 353 359 367 373 379 383 389 397 401 409 419 421 431 433 439 443 449 457 461 463 467 479 487 491 499 503 509 521 523 541 ...)

Comment: It doesn't stop, it get's truncated by `say`. If you do `(1...1000).grep(*.is-prime).perl` it will show the whole sequence. Another fun oneliner is `(1..1000).grep(*.is-prime).pick(10).sort` which would pick ten random primes out of the series and sort them in ascending order.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that I rewrote the code above using C style loops mr_ron mentioned and even if the code is quite ugly, it's almost as fast as the perl5 version, 13.55s perl6 vs 12.75s perl5. Also `$m = $n div 2 - 1` rounds the number down which could truncate the end of the series, so if you ran it up to a prime, you'd miss it. It should be `$m = ($n/2).round` instead. Also the `if $p < $m` condition will erroneously report the last number as a prime since it doesn't get included in the non-primes hash. It should be `$p <= $m` instead.

Comment: I got my result with : (1..2500).hyper.grep( *.is-prime ).eager.perl.say

Comment: FTR... Reading this in 2023 I was surprised to `say` the least by .@dominix's last comment which seemed to suggest they got truncation with that code. That made no sense to me. Then I noted the upvote of their comment, and no follow up. What was going on? Concerned, I ran [`(1..2500).hyper.grep( *.is-prime ).eager.perl.say` in tio](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVJBRSvANchHLzk/tyAzJ7VIryy1qDgzP8@aS8NQT8/I1MBAUy@jsgAokV6UWqChoKWXWaxbUJSZm6qgqZeamA6UAErm6AGN@v8fAA). The result was correct -- 367 primes from 2 to 2477, with no truncation. No further comment...

Answer (score 6):

I don't think I can add much more to what Liz said. Other than:

> "but in order to benchmark multiple languages, I need to run the same
>   thing everywhere"

...where "same" is defined as similar looking syntax in English, is a *very* poor criteria for equivalence between radically different programming languages. Perl 6 has very similar or even identical syntax to Perl 5 whilst performing very different semantics underneath. The whole language has been tuned for correctness with default easily reached syntax, rather than optimal behaviour. Another great example is Perl 6 strings, they are quite slow, they are always fully normalised unicode rather than a string of plain bytes. All operations on them consider unicode concepts of graphemes rather than bytes and byte offsets. Which is great! But the more equivalent type to a C/Perl 5 string is probably a `Buf` which sadly doesn't have anywhere near as many string like operators/methods but is just a block of bytes.